# Why does the virtual keyboard show for hidden input element on Chrome on Android, but not other devices?

Tags: android, google-chrome

Steps to reproduce:
1) Go to https://hsf.ipass.com.
2) The document.activeElement input element with id=find-near-location is not visible.  It's actually collapsed in the hamburger menu.
3) Tap anywhere on the map w/o a pin.  You can even tap on a pin, but that has other interactions that muddies the issue.
4) The virtual keyboard pops up.
5) document.activeElement is still find-near-location.

It seems to be a bug in Chrome on Android, but my Google-fu is failing me.

I am running into this issue on Android 6.0.1 with Chrome 52.0.2743.98.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Bootstrap's .collapse class does not use display:none or visibility:hidden to avoid the element from being rendered, required per https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#focus-management.